# H5Py and storage

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I am writing some code which needs to save a very large numpy array to memory. The numpy array is so large in fact that I cannot load it all into memory at once. But I can calculate the array in chunks. I.e. my code looks something like:

```
for i in np.arange(numberOfChunks):

   myArray[(i*chunkSize):(i*(chunkSize+1)),:,:] = #... do some calculation
```

As I can't load `myArray` into memory all at once, I want to save it to a file one "chunk" at a time. i.e. I want to do something like this:

```
for i in np.arange(numberOfChunks):

   myArrayChunk = #... do some calculation to obtain chunk

   saveToFile(myArrayChunk, indicesInFile=[(i*chunkSize):(i*(chunkSize+1)),:,:], filename)
```

I understand this can be done with `h5py` but I am a little confused how to do this. My current understanding is that I can do this:

```
import h5py

# Make the file
h5py_file = h5py.File(filename, "a")

# Tell it we are going to store a dataset
myArray = h5py_file.create_dataset("myArray", myArrayDimensions, compression="gzip")


for i in np.arange(numberOfChunks):

   myArrayChunk = #... do some calculation to obtain chunk

   myArray[(i*chunkSize):(i*(chunkSize+1)),:,:] = myArrayChunk
```

But this is where I become a little confused. I have read that if you index a `h5py` datatype like I did when I wrote `myArray[(i*chunkSize):(i*(chunkSize+1)),:,:]`, then this part of `myArray` has now been read into memory. So surely, by the end of my loop above, have I not still got the whole of `myArray` in memory now? How has this saved my memory?

Similarly, later on, I would like to read in my file back in one chunk at a time, doing further calculation. i.e. I would like to do something like:

```
import h5py

# Read in the file
h5py_file = h5py.File(filename, "a")

# Read in myArray
myArray = h5py_file['myArray']

for i in np.arange(numberOfChunks):

   # Read in chunk
   myArrayChunk = myArray[(i*chunkSize):(i*(chunkSize+1)),:,:]

   # ... Do some calculation on myArrayChunk
```

But by the end of this loop is the whole of `myArray` now in memory? I am a little confused by when `myArray[(i*chunkSize):(i*(chunkSize+1)),:,:]` is in memory and when it isn't. Please could someone explain this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the basic idea. Take care when saying "save to memory". NumPy arrays are saved in memory (RAM). HDF5 data is saved on disk (not to memory/RAM!), then accessed (memory used depends on how you access). In the first step you are creating and writing data in chunks to the disk. In the second step you are accessing data from disk in chunks. Working example provided at the end.

When reading data with `h5py` there 2 ways to read the data:
This returns a NumPy array:
`myArrayNP = myArray[:,:,:]`
This returns a h5py dataset object that operates like a NumPy array:
`myArrayDS = myArray`

The difference: h5py dataset objects are not read into memory all at once. You can then slice them as needed. Continuing from above, this is a valid operation to get a subset of the data:
`myArrayChunkNP = myArrayDS[i*chunkSize):(i+1)*chunkSize),:,:]`

My example also corrects 1 small error in your chunksize increment equation.
You had:
`myArray[(i*chunkSize):(i*(chunkSize+1)),:,:] = myArrayChunk`
You want:
`myArray[(i*chunkSize):(i+1)*chunkSize),:,:] = myArrayChunk`

**Working Example (writes and reads):**

```
import h5py
import numpy as np

# Make the file
with h5py.File("SO_61173314.h5", "w") as h5w:

    numberOfChunks = 3
    chunkSize = 4
    print( 'WRITING %d chunks with w/ chunkSize=%d ' % (numberOfChunks,chunkSize) )
    # Write dataset to disk
    h5Array = h5w.create_dataset("myArray", (numberOfChunks*chunkSize,2,2), compression="gzip")

    for i in range(numberOfChunks):

       h5ArrayChunk = np.random.random(chunkSize*2*2).reshape(chunkSize,2,2)
       print (h5ArrayChunk)

       h5Array[(i*chunkSize):((i+1)*chunkSize),:,:] = h5ArrayChunk


with h5py.File("SO_61173314.h5", "r") as h5r:
    print( '/nREADING %d chunks with w/ chunkSize=%d/n' % (numberOfChunks,chunkSize) )

    # Access myArray dataset - Note: This is NOT a NumpPy array
    myArray = h5r['myArray']

    for i in range(numberOfChunks):

       # Read a chunk into memory (as a NumPy array)
       myArrayChunk = myArray[(i*chunkSize):((i+1)*chunkSize),:,:]

       # ... Do some calculation on myArrayChunk  
       print (myArrayChunk)
```

Comment: Ah I see! Thank you! Can I ask why you have switched to using the `with` keyword? Is there a reason this syntax may be better performance wise? When I tried my example with looping it was shockingly slow.

Comment: I am not aware of any performance benefit using `with / as:`. Python handles the file close automatically with this method. (Notice that I only open the file - there is no `.close()` statement.) Reasons I do it this way; It's cleaner, and doesn't leave a file open if a process fails.

Comment: Ah okay! Thank you!